# Inconsistent animations in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-animations

I have a button on which when you click a menu should open in an animated way and then *one by one also icons should appear inside that menu*.

In below screenshot you can see I have mostly achieved it, but strange things happen if you start to press the "+" button a little bit faster for example, you can see after opening the menu second time the right most two icons already kind of show up, which should not happen because they should show one by one.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42axy.gif)

Here is [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-wind-njb5lb?file=/src/styles.css):

HTML:

```
const AnimatedActionMenu = (props) => {
  let [active, setActive] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="animated-action-menu">
      <div className={active ? 'container active' : 'container'}>
        <div className="menu">
          <div className="menu-item" style={{ transitionDelay: '1s' }}>
            {' '}
            <DingdingOutlined />
          </div>
          <div className="menu-item" style={{ transitionDelay: '1.5s' }}>
            {' '}
            <TwitterOutlined />
          </div>
          <div className="menu-item" style={{ transitionDelay: '2s' }}>
            {' '}
            <GoogleOutlined />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          className="toggle"
          onClick={() => {
            setActive(!active);
          }}
        ></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

CSS:

```
html,
body,
#root {
  height: 100%;
}

.animated-action-menu {
  display: flex;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.animated-action-menu .container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Toggle related animations */

.animated-action-menu .container .toggle {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 72px;
  width: 72px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.animated-action-menu .container .toggle:before {
  content: '+';
  font-size: 32px;
  transition: transform 1.5s;
}
.animated-action-menu .container.active .toggle:before {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}

/* Menu related animations */

.animated-action-menu .container .menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform 0.5s, width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 1s, 0.5s, 0.5s;
  border-radius: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1-px;
}

.animated-action-menu .container.active .menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -150px);
  height: 80px;
  width: 250px;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0.5s, 0.5s;
}

/* Menu item animations */

.animated-action-menu .container .menu .menu-item {
  transition: 1s;
  transform: translateY(-30px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.animated-action-menu .container.active .menu .menu-item {
  transform: translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I would appreciate some help because I am kind of stuck, don't know what can be causing this? I think it must be react related because I am somewhat sure I have got the CSS part correct.

---

I even noticed if I temporarily remove the `transitionDelay`'s **from the JSX,** then this kind of problem disappears. So why does this happen with `transitionDelay`'s? (ps I need transition delays)

Comment: You can leave `transitionDelay` in **JSX** but just reduce the time to "0.4, 0.5, 0.6" and it will work much better... I think problem is when you close your popup the icons again have delay and then they have to do transition again and when you open popup again they haven't yet been finished with animation... Play around with times of animations and delays and you will get it right fast. Hope i helped a little bit.

Comment: @SinisaM Thanks but IMHO this is not proper solution, what if someone wants larger delays? Should it behave like this? Do you think this is due to react? Would such thing also happen in pure html/css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set equal time for `transitionDelay` when item are not active.
You need to change the following line:

```
<div className="menu-item" style={{ transitionDelay:active ? "1s":"0s" }}>
    {" "}
    <DingdingOutlined />
</div>
<div className="menu-item" style={{ transitionDelay:active ? "1.5s":"0s"}}>
    {" "}
    <TwitterOutlined />
</div>
<div className="menu-item" style={{ transitionDelay:active ? "2s":"0s"}}>
    {" "}
    <GoogleOutlined />
</div>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-brook-ftd1yj)

Sync you use `transitionDelay` it affect both transition start and end
when you press collapse key, the delay applied on item and opacity is not 0, because of delay.
If you click on expand button faster than 1.5s or 2s, since the opacity is not set yet, the item is visible.

Comment: Can you add explanation why it works now? Was this react specific problem?

Comment: you have been set delay for both start transition and end transition
if you click on expand button faster than 1.5s or 2s, since the item opacity is not set yet, it will be visible

Comment: It's not React problem @john